# How find MyLocationButton on Google maps Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location-button

This is how I enable my location button so it can be clicked on the map:

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

My question is, how to find this button and store it in a variable so it can be displayed or not according to the logic of my app? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it via [`findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)) on `MapFragment` root view. With code like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    ...
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;
    private View mMyLocationButtonView = null;
    ...


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String [] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                mMyLocationButtonView = mMapFragment.getView().findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton");
                mMyLocationButtonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you'll got something like that:

[image: MyLocationButton with custom background]

Comment: Flawless, thanks you! But one small question, why is that `Runnable` necessary?

Comment: You are right, you can use only `View buttonView = mMapFragment.getView().findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton");` - `Runnable` is necessary for `myLocationButton` layout changes (e.g. resizing).

Comment: Thanks again Andrii!

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the My Location button from appearing by calling `UiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false)`.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location#my-location

Comment: Thanks but your solution doesn't answer my question. My question is, how to find that button and store it in a variable?

Comment: You can't do that. You can hold a reference to the GoogleMap object if you want can call googleMap.getSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false) if you want

Comment: The specific view is a private implementation detail of the GoogleMap object. You can get it view a findViewById, but there is no guarantee that Google won't change the view id and break your code (because its a private piece of code). Its not safe to do that.

Comment: How can I get it using `findViewById`?